# heroku toolbelt command issues

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I installed the Heroku Toolbelt following the instructions provided by RailsBridge's Installfest for Windows.  I am running Windows 10 64-bit and the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails provided by RailsBridge.

Each heroku command I attempt to input, be it 'version', 'login', or what have you, I get this:

```
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies... done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...Error reading plugin: heroku-cli addons.
```

Then I see a list of which plugins that there were reading errors for.  The list is:
    heroku-apps;
    heroku-fork; 
    heroku-git;
    heroku-local;
    heroku-run;
    heroku-status

Then:

```
ERROR: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Then it repeats this, adding dependencies, attempting to install core plugins, same reading plugin errors, but then after the runtime error runs again, it prints this:

```
! error getting commands pid 5052 exit 1
```

Previously, it was 'error getting commands pid 6912' or something like that.  I looked around a bit and didn't see anything that specifically dealt with this, but I am sorry if I missed it before asking this question.  I'm very new at this.

I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to correct this.  I thank you very much ahead of time!

Edit:  I now understand what pid is.  Using another resource, I was told to check for the pid process in my task manager.  I reran this process, got a different pid number, and searched for it in my task manager but to no avail.  It isn't storing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and Heroku support team was quick to answer with:

> can you delete ~/.heroku/heroku-cli and try again?

Next time you run a `heroku` command it will reinstall the toolbelt. Worked for me.

According to the support team it happened because:

> It was a bug that was pushed yesterday we fixed this morning that some users ran into.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

This worked!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Got a very similar issue, doing just these steps solved my issue, thanks!

Comment: Got the same issue, I had to uninstall heroku toolbelt and reinstall it.